# Why did Lt Col Gold report Sgt Dohun to Lt Rafferty?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-bridge-too-far

I quote [*A Bridge Too Far* (1977)'s transcript](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=bridge-too-far-a) from [1:39:06](https://youtu.be/H21zi9hj9-A?t=5946)/2:56:12.

> If you don't look at him right now,
>   he's going to die.
>   He's dead now.
>   It'd mean a lot to me
>   if you'd check him out.
>   Come on, Sergeant.
>   For Christ's sake, get him out of here.
>   Would you look at him,
>   please, sir...
>   right now...
>   or I'll blow
>   your fuckin' head off.
>   Right now.
>   I can give him a quick examination,
>   if you like.
>   Thank you very much, sir.
>   Son of a bitch.
>   Orderly!
>   Well, I got the bullet
>   out of his skull.
>   -He's gonna live though, right?
>   -He's gonna have one hell of a headache.
>   Guess you can turn me in now, sir.
>   That was a court-martial offense.
>   You understand that?
>   - Yes, sir.
>   - Hope to hell it was worth it.
>   Guess only time
>   will tell on that, sir.
>   My response is strictly limited,
>   regardless of my personal preference.
>   - You understand that too?
>   - I do.
>   Like somebody cheating in school.
>   Once word gets out that you can behave
>   any way you goddamn please...
>   discipline's gone,
>   forget about getting it back.
>   So you're gonna have to be arrested,
>   over and out. Lieutenant Rafferty.
>   Yes, sir, Colonel.
>   Lieutenant Rafferty,
>   this is Sergeant... What's your name?
>   Eddie Dohun.
>   Sergeant Dohun pulled a gun on me
>   and threatened to kill me...
>   unless I did precisely
>   what he ordered.
>   - I want you to put him under arrest.
>   - Yes, sir.
>   I want you to keep him there
>   for at least ten seconds.
>   - I'm not all that sure I understand.
>   - Count to ten, Lieutenant, fast.
>   One, two, three, four, five, six,
>   seven, eight, nine, ten. Like that?
>   Thank you, Lieutenant.
>   This is yours, I think.
>   It sure looks like mine.
>   You scared the shit out of me,
>   you stupid bastard.
>   You did a fine job yourself,
>   if it makes you feel any better.
>   Goddamn right it does.
>   - Eddie?
>   - Sir.
>   You wouldn't really
>   have killed me, would you?
>   [Staff Sgt Eddie Dohun salutes, portrayed by James Caan.]
>   Thank you, sir.

I'm divining from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Bridge_Too_Far_(film)#Allies) that the US surgeon is      Chief Division Surgeon Lt Col. David Gold, 101st Airborne Division Clearing Station  portrayed by Arthur Hill.

Anyways, I'm surmising that the surgeon realizes his wholly wrong diagnosis and somewhat reproaches himself.

1. But then why did he bring up Sgt Dohun's threat, let alone a Lt that undeniably outranks a Sgt? Wouldn't a bona fide repenter just hush?
2. Why did he ask Lt Rafferty to "keep him there for at least ten seconds"?

Comment: I have to say (among other possible problems with this barrage of multiple *A Bridge Too Far* questions compressed into one) these transcript quotes are kinda crap. Is there any possibility to introduce some much needed formatting in order to clarify who actually said what in those scenes (provided the quotes are relevant for the question to begin with, of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyways, I'm surmising that the surgeon realizes his wholly wrong
>   diagnosis and somewhat reproaches himself.

I agree.

> But then why did he bring up Sgt Dohun's threat, let alone a Lt that undeniably outranks a Sgt? Wouldn't a bona fide repenter just hush?

For the reasons he gives in the immediately preceding lines:

> "Like somebody cheating in school. Once word gets out that you can behave any way you goddamn please... discipline's gone, forget about getting it back"

If it's ever the case the rules aren't followed, even once, a breakdown of order would follow. I don't understand what you said about rank.

> Why did he ask Lt Rafferty to "keep him there for at least ten seconds"?

He wants Dohun punished, for his offence - but not punished *too much*, since Dohun was after all right.